# Imagen HTML SRC Android AsyncTask

Tags: android, asynctask, src

Buenas tardes, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android que necesita consumir Web Service, pero el detalle está que el contenido de uno de los datos viene en formato de hipertexto, por lo tanto tengo que convertirlo en Android, algunas ocasiones viene con imagenes src y también tengo que mostrar, tengo el siguiente código con AsyncTask:

```
 class ConvertirDatos extends AsyncTask<Html.ImageGetter, String, Html.ImageGetter> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setTitle("Obteniendo detalles");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    **protected Html.ImageGetter doInBackground(Html.ImageGetter... imageGetters) {
        Html.ImageGetter imageHTML = new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String s) {
                try {
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(new URL(s).openStream(), "srcName");
                    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getMinimumWidth(), d.getMinimumHeight());
                    return d;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.v("IOException", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        return imageHTML;**

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Html.ImageGetter imageGetter) {
        super.onPostExecute(imageGetter);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String contenido = (String) bundle.get("contenido");


        if (contenido.equals("") && contenido !=null){
            tvContenido.setText("Para más información descarga los archivos asociados");
        }else {
            **Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(contenido, doInBackground(), null);
            tvContenido.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
            tvContenido.setLinksClickable(true);
            tvContenido.setText(s);**
        }


        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

El detalle está en cuando cargo imagenes pesadas, se carga en el Hilo principal, no me muestra el progressDialog, y se queda la pantalla en negro, no sé si estoy implementando mal el AsyncTask.

Gracias por la ayuda. Feliz año

Comment: Los "**" no deben ir en el código. Debes agregar como llamas el AsyncTask. En cuanto a esto "tengo que convertirlo en Android, algunas ocasiones viene con imagenes src"  ¿como lo realizas? ,  revisar [ask].

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, se lo puse para marcar en negrita. La imagen la convierto con el doInBackground y el texto a convertir lo hago así: \n Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(contenido, doInBackground(), null);
            tvContenido.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
            tvContenido.setLinksClickable(true);
            tvContenido.setText(s); \n lo que viene en "**"

Comment: Sé que está realizando el proceso por que cuando no convierte las imagenes, se ve el texto, pero cuando si tiene que cargar las imagenes se vuelve la pantalla en negro y no responde

Comment: Me refería a como llamas ConvertirDatos  ?

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, gracias por el tiempo en comentar, en el Oncreate lo llamo así ConvertirDatos convertirDatos = new ConvertirDatos();
        convertirDatos.execute();